# Way to add gem file to Dashing framework

Tags: ruby, rally, dashboard, dashing

I need to use Rally API dev kit [rally_rest_api gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rally_rest_api/versions/1.1.0). I'm new with ruby. Is the any way to do it quickly ?
Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 2):

You should have a file called `Gemfile` in the root of your Dashing project. It should already contain the `dashing` gem itself:

```
gem 'dashing'
```

Simply add the following below it:

```
gem 'rally_rest_api'
```

And run `bundle install`. To actually use the gem in your project, take a look at the [documentation](http://rally-rest-api.rubyforge.org/rally_rest_api/).

Comment: Note, this relies on you having bundler installed already -- probably a safe assumption. If you get errors, you'll need to `gem install bundler` before running `bundle install`.